# Can I develop a feature for Stack Overflow and get recommendation by Stack Overflow for my work?

Tags: discussion

**Some background:**

I am a newbie coder and was struggling on Stack Overflow to get answers and reputation (reputation is secondary). Now after having this experience I have many really awesome ideas to improve Stack Overflow.

**Main question:**

1. if I improve Stack Overflow and add a totally UNIQUE feature, will I get any kind of recommendation letter, identity as a developer by Stack Overflow?
2. Can I work along with the Stack Overflow team to develop those features?

Comment: You can make [tag:feature-request] proposals here. Community and SE devs will decide if they are worth it.

Comment: You need to hack Stack Overflow unless you are allowed to be in the team. I am sure the security is robust here ;)

Answer (score 13):

> if I improve stackoverflow and add a totally UNIQUE feature , will i get any kind of recommendation letter , identity as developer by stackoverflow ?

If you just propose a feature (here on meta or by sending a message directly to SE) then no.  You wouldn't be recognized as a developer as a result.  You could refer people to that proposal (if you did so on meta, rather than privately) as an indication that you suggested the idea, but that's pretty much the extent of your recognition.

> Can I work along with stackoverflow team to develop those features ?

You can apply for a job to work there.  They're always taking applications.  If they decide to hire you, then it's at least *possible* that some of the things you end up working on may be your ideas.

Answer (score 9):

Stack Overflow writes their own code to build the site.  Unless you are an employee, you won't be able to directly affect their code.

That being said, there is a community of people who write [Stack apps](https://stackapps.com/) to enhance their experience of Stack Overflow.  Many of those are open source, but they still won't give you anything official from Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 4):

The core Q/A engine is proprietary software. See [Servy's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336142/578411) answer for background on that.

You can however participate on the few components that are open-sourced. Visit the [Stack Overflow github](https://github.com/StackExchange) project, fork any repository you have idea's for and when you're done implementing/testing submit a pull request.

Trying your skills on those projects gives you the feel for what is needed from a software engineer wanting to work on the core Q/A engine.